# Activity no se muestra

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

Buen dia, estoy aprendiendo a programar en java con la herramienta de Android Studio... Estoy intentando llamar a otra activity mediante un boton pero en el emulador, al presionar el boton, la aplicacion se cierra y el IDE me da este error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: andresk21.com.speedex, PID: 3161
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
   at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
   at andresk21.com.speedex.MainActivity.llamarSegundoActiviy(MainActivity.java:29)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Y he utilizado el siguiente codigo en la clase:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button boton;
    EditText paquete;
    Integer numPaquete;
    String texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
    }

    public void llamarSegundoActiviy(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScrollingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Lo mando a llamar en la propiedad del boton `onClick`:

> **android:onClick="llamarSegundoActiviy"**

Como ya mencione, estoy en los primeros pasos de aprendizaje en esta herramienta y plataforma, de antemano gracias.

Tambien ya lo he declarado en el manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ScrollingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scrolling"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN2" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Agrego el `ScrollingActivity`...

```
package andresk21.com.speedex;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hay esta el error. Elimina de la etiqueta activity de la clase `ScrollingActivity` la etiqueta `<intent-filter>`. Para abrir una actividad esa etiqueta no es necesaria. Tiene otros usos mas específicos, pero no es necesaria para abrir una actividad. Por ejemplo en el MainActivity la utilizas para definirla como actividad por defecto, y no pueden haber dos actividades por defecto. Ese es el origen del error.

Comment: Sigue dando error pero en la segunda linea del error dice              
                                                                                                         
>Process: andresk21.com.speedex, PID: 3794 (El PID cambió) @David

Comment: En la etiqueta `<activity>`  de la actividad `.ScrollingActivity` elimina todo menos la etiqueta `android:name=".ScrollingActivity"`. Compila y me dejas saber.

Comment: Si dejo solo el `android:name` ni siquiera corre.... Dejo `android:label` y `android:theme` (solo con esos dos me deja) y el error sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: Tu clase `ScrollingActivity` extiende de `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: @AndresHenriquez podrías agregar ScrollingActivity ? veo que además tienes el error:  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: @Jorgesys ahora lo pongo

Comment: @David Si extiende a `appCompatActivity`

Comment: @AndresHenriquez ya le encontraste solución a tu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El llamado de tu método desde la vista es correcto:

```
android:onClick="llamarSegundoActiviy"
```

este método realiza un Intent  para `cargarScrollingActivity` :

```
   public void llamarSegundoActiviy(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScrollingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

pero surge un error y el mensaje es:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

en este caso no es propiamente la definición del método o el llamado al método, en este caso no es necesario definir un intent-filter en la clase `ScrollingActivity` :

```
    <activity android:name=".ScrollingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_scrolling"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Además asegura `ScrollingActivity` extienda de Activity, AppCompatActivity, etc...

Comment: Exactamente como tu dices tengo el proyecto

Answer (score 2):

El error esta en el `<intent-filter>` de la actividad `ScrollingActivity`, eliminala. Para abrir una actividad esa etiqueta no es necesaria. Tiene otros usos mas específicos, pero no es necesaria para abrir una actividad. Por ejemplo en el MainActivity la utilizas para definirla como actividad por defecto, y no pueden haber dos actividades por defecto. Ese es el origen del error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".ScrollingActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Ah si, tambien ya hice eso, lo siento ahora edito